# Parachain support for light clients

Tags: parachain, runtime, api, light-client

What is required from a technical point of view `(specific pallets and APIs)` for parachains to support light clients? I saw that only a few parachains have the option to interact with the light clients.

Answer (score 1):

As for [Smoldot](https://github.com/smol-dot/smoldot#does-smoldot-support-blockchain), it can connect to the Relay chains we know today and all its parachains. However, there is a long list of small things that smoldot or high level UIs assume are done a certain way when connecting to a chain. For example, Smoldot won't be compatible if parachains:

- use different networking protocols
- use a different trie format
- change the number of bytes of the block number
- use different hash function
- decide to not have the metadata
- and more such a like

But other than that, Smoldot should be good to go!